# 'Cannot find type in scope' error when access public enum as class variable in swift

Tags: swift, enums

how can I use enum under extension into another class? I have no problem to use it under function directly. However I got 'Cannot find type '.home' in scope' error when set as a variable

```
extension Color {

    public enum ColorUsage {
        case home([String])
        case school([String])
        case park([String])

        var description: String {
            switch self {
            case .home: return "my home"
            case .school: return "kid school"
            case .park: return "family park"
            }
        }

        func getValue() -> [String] {
            switch self {
            case .home(let value),
                 .school(let value),
                 .park(let value):
                return value
            }
        }
    }

    func findColor(places: [ColorUsage]) {
        for eachPlace in places {
            ...
        }
    }
}




class MyClass {
    func useColor() {
        let places = [.home(["home1", "home2"]), .school(["AAA", "BBB"]), .park(["you park", "his park"])] /// issue with 'Cannot find type '.home' in scope'
        let places = Color.findColor(places: places)

        let places = Color.findColor(places: [.home(["home1", "home2"]), .school(["AAA", "BBB"]), .park(["you park", "his park"])]) /// no issue
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add the SwiftUI tag to your question since it references the SwiftUI `Color` type.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing array concrete type and `findColor` method is used by Color instance not Color type, change the method to static.

```swift
import SwiftUI

extension Color {
    ...
    static func findColor(places: [ColorUsage]) {
        for eachPlace in places {
            ...
        }
    }
}

class MyClass {
    func userColor() {
        let places: [Color.ColorUse] = [
            .home(["home1", "home2"]), 
            .school(["AAA", "BBB"]), 
            .park(["you park", "his park"])
        ]

        //Now it's available to use findColor
        let home = Color.findColor(places: places)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler needs more clues about the type of array you are creating.

Try:

```swift
let places: [Color.ColorUsage] = [.home(["home1", "home2"]), .school(["AAA", "BBB"]), .park(["you park", "his park"])]
```

Comment: I have `Cannot find type 'Color' in scope`. why?

Comment: Try ```import SwiftUI```

Comment: @jacobcan118 From the code you have posted it dosen't look like the enum has any relation to the type `Color` other than its name. So unless there is a relation in some code you haven't posted you should declare it as a standalone type to avoid having to import SwiftUI and since it doesn't make any sense to declare it in an extension if there is no relationship between the two types.